# How to export and make a virtual box .vdi bootable

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, iso-image, bootable-media

I have recently been working on a modified version of Windows 7 in virtual box and am now happy enough with it that I want to try it on an actual machine however I can seem to figure out how to export as a .iso or even if it would work if I could.

Any tips / hints on how  Can make my version of Windows 7 installable via a DVD or USB from VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need first to run Sysprep (with OOBE and Generalize), and after the reboot you need to boot from WinPE and capture an image with ImageX.
After you've captured the volume image, you'll need to replace Sources\Install.wim file in the original ISO, recompile it (oscdimg or such), and burn it.

You'll need to download [Microsoft Windows AIK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753) (it contains all the utilities you'll need).

Anyway, this are all just guidelines - you'll need to do some more reading if you want to do it properly or if you'd like some other more flexible options.